# Strategies for dealing with Circular references caused by JPA relationships?

Tags: java, jpa, module, packaging

I am trying to partition my application into modules by features packaged into separate jars such as feature-a.jar, feature-b.jar, ... etc.

Individual feature jars such as feature-a.jar should contain all the code for a feature a including jpa entities, business logic, rest apis, unit tests, integration test ... etc.

The problem I am running into is that bi-directional relationships between JPA entities cause circular references between the jar files. For example Customer entity should be in customer.jar and the Order should be in order.jar but Customer references order and order references customer making it hard to split them into separate jars / eclipse projects.

**Options I see for dealing with the circular dependencies in JPA entities:**

- Option 1: Put all the entities into one jar / one project
- Option 2: Don't map certain bi-directianl relationships to avoid circular dependencies across projects.

**Questions:**

- What rules / principles have you used to decide when to do bi-directional mapping vs. not?
- Have you been able to break jpa entities into their own projects / jar by features if so how did you avoid the circular dependencies issues?

Comment: Franky, if the entities are all part of the same application, I don't see what splitting the entities into several jars brings except additional complexity.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rules have you used to decide for Circular reference in `JPA`. I also have to test it.

In my example, there is an entity `Category` Which have `OneToOne` to `parentCategory` and `OneToMany` to `childCategories` as bidirectional.

I think, the `Circular Reference`  like below data structure.

```
CategoryID      Name    ParentID
001             AAA     002
002             BBB     003
003             CCC     004
004             DDD     001
```

I would like to suggest which is to avoid problematically.

Example :

```
public void addNewCategory(Category category) {
    checkCircularity(Category category, category.getParent());
}


public static void checkCircularity(Category child, Cagegory parent) throws CircularReferenceException {
    if (superior != null) {
        if (sub.isEqual(superior) || sub.isEqual(parent.getParent())) {
            throw new CircularReferenceException("Circularity Referencing.........");
        } else if (finder.getSuper(superior) != null) {
            checkCircularity(child, parent.getParent());
        }
    }
}
```

If the program does not throw `CircularReferenceException`, there is no circular reference for that `Category` instance.

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for the circularity I am concerned with is between the java classes, not not been data that is in the database. I still found your solution useful so I up voted it.

Comment: @ams Each data of the database is represent each java instance